# How can I rectify my selection and insertion sort algorithms

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I wrote selection and insertion sort algorithms that are giving me wrong unsorted outputs. Here is my code for the selection sort:

```
public class SelectionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {23,43,45,3,54,55,23,12,22};

        int min;
        int temp = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for(int j = i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
            {
                if(arr[j] < arr[min])
                {
                    min = j;

                }
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[min];
                arr[min] = temp;
            }

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }


    }

}
```

> Output: 45 55 54 43 23 23 22 12 3

This is not sorted and I want it to sort in ascending order.

Here is my insertion sort:

```
public class Insertion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {2,4,6,5,4,3,5,3};

        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];

            int j = i;

            while( j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j])
            {
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                j = j-1;
            }
            arr[j] = temp;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

> Output: 2 4 5 4 3 5 3 6

Answer (score 1):

In your selection sort, let's focus on this part of the code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] < arr[min])
            {
                min = j;

            }
            temp = arr[j];   // <---
            arr[j] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = temp;
        }
    }
```

The high-level idea behind selection sort is to find the smallest element in the range [i, n) and then swap it with the element at position i. Notice that with the code you have here, you're constantly swapping the current index with the index of the min, which isn't the swap that you want to make. As a hint, make at most one swap per iteration of the outer loop, and have that swap be between position `i` and position `min`. If you're swapping earlier than this, you'll get the wrong answer.

For your insertion sort, there's a more subtle error. Here's where the error is:

```
while( j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j])
{
    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
    j = j-1;
}
arr[j] = temp;
```

Notice that whenever the current element compares less than the element before it, you overwrite the current element with the element before it, then decrement j. However, you don't update `arr[j-1]` with the current element, so in the next comparison, you're comparing the element that used to be in position `j-1` with the element that's in position `j-2`, rather than comparing the current element against the element in position `j-2`. To fix this, update the comparison to always compare against `temp` rather than `arr[j]`:

```
while( j > 0 && arr[j-1] > temp)
{
    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
    j = j-1;
}
arr[j] = temp;
```